# How can I limit firearms and futuristic technology in a multiverse setting?

Tags: gm-techniques, balance, gurps-4e, firearms

I'm going to start a series of Infinite Worlds campaigns and I want to prevent things like using firearms/laser/etc... on worlds where the technology is low.

Because, you know, what is preventing PCs from just using a machine gun or a tank to conquer any middle age world?

Answer (score 5):

## Logistic Nightmares

It's not that you can't bring a beam weapon to another world, but you'll quickly run into problems maintaining it operational, because like our guns it's a finicky thing whose reliability suffers without proper maintenance.

## Reliance on Divergent Physics

Something of a cop-out, but canonically at least some worlds in IW have different physical laws. Have it just so happen that many or most technologies above a desired level tend to be built using such world-specific physics, which means that they're likely to fail in other worlds.

## Emphasise the Secret

Make it so that showing blatantly high-tech gear results in easily-identifiable rumours, which in turn results in powers that be bringing down the hammer. For a full brunt of the hammer, nudge the crossworld situation in a way that would make both Infinity and Centrum angry about such renegade forces and jointly act to thwart such unsubtle conquerors. Maybe broaden the phenomenon of destabilising Echos to non-Echo world types to justify that.

Answer (score 3):

As @vicky_molokh wrote, Infinite Worlds includes power struggles between world-hopping organizations, and so conspicuously using high technology may likely tend to attract their attention, so using a gun, tank or laser can tend to backfire by attracting multiple very aggressive types who also have such technology and you will have given away that you're such a person, whereas they may be carefully maintaining their local disguises until they strike.

But I'm writing to add that also, players and speculators often greatly overestimate the dominance they could get by bringing a few higher tech weapons into a lower tech setting. Largely because they tend to greatly underestimate the intelligence and cunning of the people in the lower tech setting, and because they don't really think through the full situation.

For example, a machinegun will certainly let you kill some people and have a great effect... until you run out of ammunition, or it jams. And an SMG might not even be that great against people with armor and shields, also because they're not very accurate.

But far worse than all of that is that the people you hope to dominate will tend to include very smart and crafty people, and using a super weapon will attract many such people's attention. They will want your super weapon, and they will use their intelligence to get it from you, one way or another.

In gaming such situations, I've seen them end quite quickly in various ways, including stealth, night attacks, backstabbing, poison, surprise attacks, superior numbers, magic (Reverse Missiles trumps high-tech ranged weapons), and various deceptions.

Comment: The empire versus the ewoks....

Answer (score 1):

The **High Tech Level advantage** is required to use devices with a Tech Level higher than that of the setting. If they want to use a TL 10 railgun on a TL 3 fantasy world, they get to eat a 35-point cost.

Comment: Isn't the TL level related to the PC? I mean, If he comes from a TL10 world and travel to a TL3 world with a raigun, it is level advantage? And if it is, when they have to eat it?